# How to execute a conditional prebuild event in a .Net 6 Project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We recently converted our web apps from .Net Framework to .Net 6.  One of the web apps had the following prebuild event defined and it always worked fine.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == "Debug" npm run build --prefix $(ProjectDir) && if $(ConfigurationName) == "Debug" npm run build --prefix $(ProjectDir)Vue
```

It no longer works in the .Net 6 version of the same web app.  If I remove the if $(ConfigurationName) == "Debug" leaving only the npm runs, it works fine.  If I echo $(ConfigurationName), I get Debug.  I'm not sure why the if statement is failing.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not .NET Framework 4+2. Even the project file format is different - and a lot simpler. You can't just copy stuff from an old `csproj` file.

Comment: In the question's case, the old line behavior was *inconsistent*. In `if $(ConfigurationName) == "Debug"` the parameter is treated as a quoted string, while in `npm run build --prefix $(ProjectDir)` it's treated as a *raw* string. In the new project format, the parameters are always treated the same - as raw strings

Comment: Um, yeah, I realize it's not .net framework 4 + 2 but a later version of .net core and things work a bit differently.  But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Removing the quotes around Debug fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator is using to compare strings. Therefore try:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" npm run build --prefix $(ProjectDir) && if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" npm run build --prefix $(ProjectDir)Vue
```

You can see the differences if insert two following lines to your script:

```
echo "$(ConfigurationName)"
echo $(ConfigurationName)
```

---

An additional information about the the [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if)